# Running JMeter as a "pure" web application

Tags: jmeter, java-web-start, jnlp, openwebstart

Is it possible to run JMeter as a "pure" web application?
I am trying to convert the jmeter desktop application to webapp using java web start.

I signed all the jars in jmeter. Everything is in the root of the web application. When I click on the jnlp link all is downloaded fine, I am prompted to trust the application as expected. However jmeter wouldn't start, nothing happens after that.